# Set up apache reverse proxy for different apps in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, apache2, tomcat7, reverse-proxy

I have two apps in tomcat. I set up the reverse proxy for one of them. The app folder is **test**. The problem is when I hit the url for the app, **/test** is added to the url. 
Below is the configuration file for the reverse proxy in the sites-available folder:

**`test.eunice.lan`**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName test.eunice.lan

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/test/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/test/

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `ProxyPass` configuration is going to lead to mass confusion because the URL prefix is not the same as the context path. This would be better:

```
ProxyPass /test/ http://localhost:8080/test/
```

If you don't want to add `/test` to the beginning of your URL, then you should re-name `test.war` to `ROOT.war` (or exploded-WAR directory `test/` -> `ROOT/`) (case-sensitive, even on case-insensitive filesystems).

If you have **two** webapps then you'll definitely want to separate them by URL prefix (e.g. `/test` and `/dev` otherwise you will end up with `JSESSIONID` cookie-confusion, assuming that you are using cookie-based sessions in both web applications.

Comment: Christopher, thanks for your answer. I understand what you're saying but I will like to create a different domain for other apps in the same tomcat installation without having to add the /app_name to any of the urls. Isn't there another way of doing this?

Comment: If you want different domains, then create more than one `<Host>` within `conf/server.xml` and use a different `appBase` for each of them. Then, you can have as many `ROOT` web applications as you want.